# Symfony2 Controller Oauth2 Callback

Tags: php, symfony, oauth, salesforce

I'm accessing an API that uses Oauth2. It's basically as follows:

1. Click Login button
2. [Controller] Runs and redirects to a specific authorization url
3. At that url, the user then "logs in"
4. After login, the API sends access token to the callback url (which is specified in the settings required to get the api key)
5. Able to make API calls.

The problem is, since Symfony2 is an MVC framework, and uses controllers, I don't know how to determine the correct `callback url`. With normal php, it'd be like `rootfolder.com/callback.php`.

Is there a specific manner to do this in Symfony2 or can I just make a controller like normal, then in the routes specify a path, and that path would be the callback url?

IE in `routing.yml`:

```
oauth_callback:
    path:     /callback/
    defaults: { _controller: projectBundle:Oauth:callback }
    requirements:
        _method:  GET
```

Would this simply work, or would I need to use another solution?

Thanks!

Comment: that should work. Only you will have to generate an absolute url that you specify as callback url. To do so read this http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-absolute-urls

Comment: I think you should remove the / on the end of /callback/